# Выбор данных из двух таблиц

Tags: laravel

Есть две таблицы. Таблица пользователей и таблица операций.
В таблице операций указан внешний ключ на таблицу пользователей и прописана связь

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Но при выборе нет данных о пользователе. Мне нужно, чтобы выбрались данные из таблицы операции и по полю user_id выбралась информация о пользователе.

```
$operation = ConcurrentOperation::find(28)->users();
```

Как мне это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

заменить на

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'опционально_поле_с_id_пользователя');
}
```

Тогда

```
$operation = ConcurrentOperation::find(28);
$operationUser = $operation->user;
```

Comment: спасибо, получилось

Comment: Не создавайте 2 ответа, сообщество такое не поощряет. Лучше дополните существующий!

Comment: @Arendach спс, удалил лишний